# how to create a copy of a table in HBase on same cluster? or, how to serve requests using original state while operating on a working state

Tags: java, database, web-services, hbase

Is there an efficient way to create a copy of table structure+data in HBase, in the same cluster?  Obviously the destination table would have a different name.  What I've found so far:

1. The CopyTable job, which has been described as a tool for copying data between *different* HBase clusters.  I think it would support intra-cluster operation, but have no knowledge on whether it has been designed to handle that scenario efficiently.
2. Use the export+import jobs.  Doing that sounds like a hack but since I'm new to HBase maybe that might be a real solution?

Some of you might be asking why I'm trying to do this.  My scenario is that I have millions of objects I need access to, in a "snapshot" state if you will.  There is a batch process that runs daily which updates many of these objects.  If any step in that batch process fails, I need to be able to "roll back" to the original state.  Not only that, during the batch process I need to be able to serve requests to the original state.

Therefore the current flow is that I duplicate the original table to a working copy, continue to serve requests using the original table while I update the working copy.  If the batch process completes successfully I notify all my services to use the new table, otherwise I just discard the new table.

This has worked fine using BDB but I'm in a whole new world of really large data now so I might be taking the wrong approach.  If anyone has any suggestions of patterns I should be using instead, they are more than welcome.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data in HBase has a certain timestamp.  You can do reads (Gets and Scans) with a parameter indicating that you want to the latest version of the data as of a given timestamp.  One thing you could do would be to is to do your reads to server your requests using this parameter pointing to a time before the batch process begins.  Once the batch completes, bump your read timestamp up to the current state.

A couple things to be careful of, if you take this approach:

- HBase tables are configured to store the most recent N versions of a given cell.  If you overwrite the data in the cell with N newer values, then you will lose the older value during the next compaction.  (You can also configure them to with a TTL to expire cells, but that doesn't quite sound like it matches your case).
- Similarly, if you delete the data as part of your process, then you won't be able to read it after the next compaction.

So, if you don't issue deletes as part of your batch process, and you don't write more versions of the same data that already exists in your table than you've configured it to save, you can keep serving old requests out of the same table that you're updating.  This effectively gives you a snapshot.

Comment: Thanks Dave!  I had been considering using the timestamp dimension as an alternative to copying, but was afraid of unchecked growth (or a  slow delete process to remove old timestamp manually).  I overlooked or forgot the "recent N" behavior with respect to timestamps.  Now that you've pointed that out, the timestamp idea will actually work for my use case.

Thanks again!